# Fill Columns with TRUE or FALSE based on other Dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

Unfortunately I have a problem and would have to ask for your support.

I have a list of the most popular pet names. From the dataframe x, it appears that "Jerry" is the most popular mouse name, "Garfield" is the second most popular cat name, and so on.

```
x <- data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Mice", "Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs" ,"Birds", "Birds", "Birds"),
            names = c("Jerry", "Speedy", "Feivel", "Tom", "Garfield", "Pumpkin", "Snoopy", "Pluto", "Sirius", "Tweety", "Donald", "Hedwig"),
            rank = rep(c(1,2,3),4))
```

Dataframe y also contains pets and their names:

```
y <- data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Birds"),
            names = c("Pam", "Michael", "Garfield", "Sirius", "Tweety"))
```

I would now like to find out if the names of the animals in dataframe y are among the most popular animal names and if so, what the rank of that name would be. Thus, three columns should be created for each of the three ranks. If there is then a match with the most popular pet names a TRUE should be entered in the column with the corresponding rank. For example, "Pam" is not one of the most popular mouse names, so FALSE is entered in each of the three columns (or NA, I wouldn't care about that). On the other hand, Garfield is one of the most popular cat names, so the value TRUE should be entered in the rank2 column. This result should be stored in dataframe z.

```
z <-  data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Birds"),
             names = c("Pam", "Michael", "Garfield", "Sirius", "Tweety"),
             rank1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
             rank2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
             rank3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I already thought about using the functions `spread()` or `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyr` package, but unfortunately I can't get the right result.

I would be very happy about your help and thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to serially `left_join()` `x` onto `y` and then convert the `NA` into `logical` at the end.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Mice", "Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs" ,"Birds", "Birds", "Birds"),
            names = c("Jerry", "Speedy", "Feivel", "Tom", "Garfield", "Pumpkin", "Snoopy", "Pluto", "Sirius", "Tweety", "Donald", "Hedwig"),
            rank = rep(c(1,2,3),4))

y <- data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Birds"),
            names = c("Pam", "Michael", "Garfield", "Sirius", "Tweety"))

y %>% 
  left_join(x %>% filter(rank == 1) %>% rename(rank1 = rank)) %>% 
  left_join(x %>% filter(rank == 2) %>% rename(rank2 = rank)) %>% 
  left_join(x %>% filter(rank == 3) %>% rename(rank3 = rank)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("rank"), ~if_else(is.na(.x), F, T)))
#>   animals    names rank1 rank2 rank3
#> 1    Mice      Pam FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 2    Cats  Michael FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 3    Cats Garfield FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 4    Dogs   Sirius FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 5   Birds   Tweety  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey Dan, thank you very much for your reply! Your solution works really well for my example! :) However, if I apply it to my original problem, the mutate function does not work as expected. The rank columns which were originally filled with FALSE became TRUE. Unfortunately, I'm not really used to working with across() ... do you have any idea?

Comment: I guess I could solve it by including an OR-operator. I changed the mutate function to: mutate(across(starts_with("rank"), ~if_else(is.na(.x) | .x == FALSE, F, T)))

Comment: If you're adding more 'rank' columns after the first 3, one option is to wait and do the `mutate()` at the end. Otherwise, your code above looks like it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `left_join`. What is different with the above solutions is that I only use one `left_join`, and use an `ifelse` statement to assign `NA` to `FALSE`, others to `TRUE`.

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(y, x, by = c("animals", "names")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "rank", values_from = "rank", names_prefix = "rank", names_sort = T) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("rank"), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), F, T))) %>% 
  select(-rankNA)

# A tibble: 5 × 5
  animals names    rank1 rank2 rank3
  <chr>   <chr>    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 Mice    Pam      FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 Cats    Michael  FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 Cats    Garfield FALSE TRUE  FALSE
4 Dogs    Sirius   FALSE FALSE TRUE 
5 Birds   Tweety   TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and support! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_wider` after just one `ìnner_join` to dummy encode the ranks into multiple logical columns. This will discard animals which are not appearing in `x` and thus have a unknown rank.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(
  animals = c("Mice", "Mice", "Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Birds", "Birds", "Birds"),
  names = c("Jerry", "Speedy", "Feivel", "Tom", "Garfield", "Pumpkin", "Snoopy", "Pluto", "Sirius", "Tweety", "Donald", "Hedwig"),
  rank = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 4)
)


y <- data.frame(
  animals = c("Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Birds"),
  names = c("Pam", "Michael", "Garfield", "Sirius", "Tweety")
)

y %>%
  inner_join(x) %>%
  # dummy encoding
  mutate(present = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = rank, values_from = present, names_prefix = "rank",  
    values_fill = list(present = FALSE)
  )
#> Joining, by = c("animals", "names")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   animals names    rank2 rank3 rank1
#>   <chr>   <chr>    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 Cats    Garfield TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 2 Dogs    Sirius   FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 3 Birds   Tweety   FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I really like the compactness of your solution, but unfortunately, the pets "Pam" and "Michael" got lost here due to the inner_join :-/

Comment: It is intentionally, because they have unknown rank meaning it does not make much sense to keep them. However, you can keep the rows with rank set to `NA` using `left_join` instead of `inner_join`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and support! :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get ranks on your `y` object is to use `left_join`. Since you just want to create three simple columns, it is probably easiest to just use `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Mice", "Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs" ,"Birds", "Birds", "Birds"),
                names = c("Jerry", "Speedy", "Feivel", "Tom", "Garfield", "Pumpkin", "Snoopy", "Pluto", "Sirius", "Tweety", "Donald", "Hedwig"),
                rank = rep(c(1,2,3),4))

y <- data.frame(animals = c("Mice", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Birds"),
                names = c("Pam", "Michael", "Garfield", "Sirius", "Tweety"))

z = left_join(y, x) %>% 
  mutate(rank1 = rank == 1,
         rank2 = rank == 2,
         rank3 = rank == 3) %>% 
  select(-rank) %>% # removing the rank column
  print()
#Joining, by = c("animals", "names")
#  animals    names rank1 rank2 rank3
#1    Mice      Pam    NA    NA    NA
#2    Cats  Michael    NA    NA    NA
#3    Cats Garfield FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#4    Dogs   Sirius FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#5   Birds   Tweety  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and support! :)